# Determine if input is numeric

Tags: c++, input, precision, cin

The below code should essentially repeat whatever double precision numerical value I pump in. But when I use "45*45" as input, for example, it will give me an output of "Value is 45", dropping everything after the *. I want it to return it as "Not a double precision numerical value". How could I do that? Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <iomanip>   
#include <cmath>   
#include <cstdlib>   
#include <cstring> 

using namespace std; 


int main() {
    double number1; //Initialize Numerical Value

std::cout << "Please input a double precision numerical value :";   
std::cin >> number1;
if (!cin) {
    cout << "Not a double precision numerical value" << endl;
}
else if (cin) {
    cout << "Value is: " << number1;
}
else {
    cout << "Error";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Read a whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and try to [parse it as a floating point number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). Follow the links, read the documentation.

Comment: '"45"` **is** a valid text representation of a floating-point value. The **next** attempted read will fail, because `'*'` cannot be part of a valid floating-point value, and there are no valid characters preceding it.